# Motivation for Jordan Canonical Form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, jordan-normal-form

I took linear algebra and understood the proof that linear operators on a vector space over an algebraically closed field have a Jordan Canonical Form. Why should I care about this theorem? I understand that it can be useful in doing some computations, but it seems that these computations are quite rare.

Indeed, I am not puzzled by *diagonalization* or *triangularization* at all. They both have practical and theoretical uses, but even more than that, they just seem like nice things to have. Can someone explain why Jordan Canonical Form is a "nice thing to have"?

Comment: You say you understand the usefulness of diagonalization. Some matrices cannot be diagonalized; but every (square) matrix over an algebraically closed field can be put in Jordan canonical form. A matrix can be diagonalized iff its Jordan canonical form is diagonal.

Comment: As far as practical uses go, Jordan Canonical Form play an important role in first order differntial (and difference) equations on $n$ variables, where generalized eigenvectors/spaces make a common appearance.

Comment: @CharlesStaats: It is often remarked that JCF is the next best thing to diagonalization. I'm (sort of) trying to ask why people say this.

Comment: As far as niceness goes, a love for Jordan Canonical Form would have to come from a love of nilpotent matrices, which are the motivating pieces behind all this anyway (remember that $A-\lambda I$ is nilpotent over the generalized eigenspace of $\lambda$).

Comment: Consider "shift operators" - operators that send a vector $p_1$ to $p_2$ then $p_2$ to $p_3$, then $p_3$ to $p_4$, and so forth, then send the last vector in the group to zero (Sort of like a conveyor belt transporting vectors to their ultimate doom). It is simple to show that such shift operators are not diagonalizable. The Jordan normal form shows the converse: shifting is essentially the *only* reason why an operator is not diagonalizable.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: indeed, that's one of the interests of JCF. If a matrix is in JCF, it's easy to compute its powers thanks to nilpotency.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most generic answer: any time that we can reduce a problem over an incredibly general object (say, a matrix) to a problem in which we have more information at our fingertips (say, the same problem but over matrices that are in JCF), we make life easier - both in terms of proving theory and in terms of practical computations.

To be more specific to the situation at hand:  the Jordan canonical form is sort of the next-best-thing to diagonalization.  If the matrix is diagonalizable, then its JCF is diagonal; if it isn't, then what you get is at least *block diagonal*, and the blocks come in a predictable form.

Comment: But the problem is that the JCF computation comes at a high prize. While in theory these results are valuable, are there any practical applications you can share with us?

Comment: @Domi: The structure provided by JCF of a matrix $A$ can be used to deduce the structure of problems where $A$ is underlying, for example the ODE $x'(t) = Ax(t)$ which is solved by $x(t) = \exp(At)x_0$. Instead of calculating that matrix exponential, we can plug in knowledge of how the matrix exponential of a JCF looks like, as shown [here](https://www.math24.net/general-solution-system-differential-equations-jordan-form/) for example.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of the JCF is to get a a linear transformation as close as possible to acting like scalar multiplication. When you restrict a linear transformation to one of its eigenspaces, by definition it is acting by scalar multiplication. However, the eigenspaces of a linear transformation will add up to the whole space only if it is diagonalizable. So, instead we consider 'generalized eigenvectors,' i.e. vectors $v$ for which $(T-\lambda I)^kv = 0$ for some power $k$ and scalar $\lambda$, as a weaker form of acting by scalar multiplication. The JCF is then the matrix of a linear transformation with respect to a full basis of generalized eigenvectors. The diagonal elements of the JCF tell you the $\lambda$, and the size of the block tells you the $k$. The beauty of the JCF then is that, if the base field contains all the eigenvalues of the linear transformation, it always exists!

Answer (score 2):

According to the Domi's comment, the good question is not "is the JCF really useful ?"; the good question is "is the JCF practically computable ?". We can consider two cases.

Case 1. One knows only a numerical approximation $\tilde{A}$ of our matrix $A\in M_n$. Then $\chi_{\tilde{A}}$, the characteristic polynomial of $\tilde{A}$ has $n$ distinct roots; note that if $A$ has in fact multiple roots, then the roots of $\chi_{\tilde{A}}$ are very close. But, no matter, we can "diagonalize" $\tilde{A}$ with a numerical calculation whose complexity is $\approx 40 n^3$. Clearly, the calculation may be unstable even if we use $QR$ method. Anyway, in such a case, the JCF is useless!

Case 2. The matrix $A$ is exactly known. For the sake of simplicity, assume that $n\geq 5$ and that $A$  is any matrix with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then we decompose $\chi_A$ in irreducible and we know when $A$ has multiple eigenvalues and we know approximations of these eigenvalues. Thus we can deduce, a priori, the form of the JCF of $A$. In these conditions, we can obtain (with the same complexity as above) an approximation of the JCF of $A$.

PS. Obviously, we can obtain the EXACT Frobenius canonical form also in $O(n^3)$; depending on the issue, this form can be very useful.

Comment: Your first paragraph is quite misguided… There are things that are not only not practically computable but in fact not computable **at all** and at the same time useful.

Answer (score 1):

G. Strang gives good motivation==> From **26:43-** in this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_zYQHmrh08. I hope this may help you.